Timeline not showing timeline of current opened file
I have a new Windows installation, and the Timeline feature doesn't seem to be working properly. Clicking the TIMELINE window does not show the git log.
I had to click the Refresh button. It then showed the git log for one particular file. When I changed the opened file in the editor, the TIMELINE window contents did not change. Clicking the Refresh button flashed the TIMELINE window, but it still showed the log for that same one file.
Are there additional Timeline settings needed to make it work?

It sounds like you pinned a file in the timeline. If you did, just click the pin button in the action bar of the timeline again.
